Turning image when I upload it to Cloudinary from Strapi
I have an admin panel based on Strapi and I want to save images in Cloudinary. When I try to do it in any collection some of images are turning before saving. How I can change it? I have no need in that
I try to change uploading config in Strapi project and also I try to change upload preset in Cloudinary settings, but I still haven`t any positive result
This is my plugin`s file:
  // ...
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: "cloudinary",
      providerOptions: {
        cloud_name: env("CLOUDINARY_NAME"),
        api_key: env("CLOUDINARY_KEY"),
        api_secret: env("CLOUDINARY_SECRET"),
      },
      actionOptions: {
        upload: {         
        },
        uploadStream: {},
        delete: {},
      },
    },
  },
  // ...
});


I'm unable to reproduce this in my own Cloudinary account. Could you please provide a code sample showing how you're making the upload, along with any parameters you're using in the upload call? It'd also be helpful to know what your Upload Preset looks like.

This is my plugin`s file:
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
// ...
upload: {
config: {
provider: "cloudinary",
providerOptions: {
cloud_name: env("CLOUDINARY_NAME"),
api_key: env("CLOUDINARY_KEY"),
api_secret: env("CLOUDINARY_SECRET"),
},
actionOptions: {
upload: {
},
uploadStream: {},
delete: {},
},
},
},
// ...
});

That information isn't sufficient. Please share more details or open a new support ticket with Cloudinary: Cloudinary Support."
